# Изменить свойства img с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно изменять ширину и высоту изображения, которое появится в результате этого кода, как получить доступ к его свойствам?

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = 'image';
div.id = 'ImageArea';
div.style.display = 'block';
div.onclick = 'Hide()';
div.innerHTML = '<div class="pic"><img src="images/' + (i+1) + '.jpg"></div>';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: совсем лень для img id прописать?) вообще, код работает? onclick особенно.

Comment: jQuery:

    $('.pic > img').width(y).height(x);

обновил*

Comment: 1-ый день учу яву, пока все быстро не доходит...
onclick работает, по крайней мере в опере точно, однако в IE нет, конечно было бы интересно узнать, как в данном случае сделать кросбраузерный обработчик клика только посредством js (т.е. без jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Прописать для `img` уникальный `id="myImg"`. Но правильней будет к `div` добавить новый объект `img` и обратиться к `document.getElemetById('myImg').width=xxxx+'px'`;

Answer (score 0):

Проще использовать Jquery так как получить значения ширинывысоты изображение, если они не указаны через CSS причем нужно что бы они были указаны в атрибуте style а не во внешнем файле css, скорее всего не удастся ...